# How can we evaluate this integral? $\displaystyle{\int_0^{\pi/2}x\tan^{n}(x)\ dx}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, closed-form

I am looking for a closed form solution to the following,
$$I_n=\int_0^{\pi/2}x\tan^{n}(x)\ dx,\quad 0\leq n<1.$$
I have tried integrating by parts to maybe introduce the Beta function, but the $\tan^n(x)$ term makes it difficult.

Substituting $x=\arctan(u)$,
$$I_n=\int_0^{\infty}u^n\underbrace{\frac{\arctan(u)}{1+u^2}}_{f(u)}\ du.$$
If I can obtain a power series expansion for $f(u)$, I can find the Mellin transform of it by Ramanujan's master theorem and the integral will follow, but I haven't been successful with this either.

Any ideas? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Never mind. I believe the integral is divergent.

Comment: But it does converge for $n\in[0,1)$. I will edit my post.

Comment: To be honest, I think there are serious issues of convergence of the integral in Jack's answer: $I_\alpha$ converges iff. $p+\alpha<0$ which, for $p>0$ fixed, means we can't evaluate the derivative at $\alpha=0$... Also the calculation of $I_\alpha$ remains unexplained

Comment: At any rate, you have the closed form you wanted

Comment: @FShrike. Thanks for linking the post by Jack. I agree with you that there are some problems with the answer, so I will leave this post open.